# Power Bi: How to create a table from slicers with individually selected data and quantities

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a database with more or less 500 assets codes, and would like to create a table/matrix resulting from the selection of the users (so that I could find differences with another table).

The idea would be more or less like this, the slicer to the left refers to the asset's code, and the one to the right to its respective quantity:

[image]

In this case, the expected result of the table/matrix would be:

```
**Asset       Value**
ALPA4           1
AMAR3           4 
**Total         5**   (it doesn't have necessarily to have a total value)
```

Does anyone have an idea if anything like it would be possible?
Thanks!

p.s.: I'm trying to reproduce the functionality of a sheet in Excel (this is why I'm trying to do something more likely to a "cell" context).

Comment: What tool are you using? Your question does not mention anything specific, and all five of your tags could apply to a wide range of tools and technologies. Please [edit] your question to clarify. Without the right tags, it is unlikely that your question will be seen by the right subject-matter experts (SMEs).

Comment: You can take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance on how to write a question which is more likely to receive good answers.